# How to change \textsc to output petite caps instead of small caps?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, small-caps

I am using FF Hertz to typeset a document. FF Hertz has both small caps and petite caps of which the latter suits my work better.

How can I redefine `\textsc` to load petite caps instead of small caps?

```
\documentclass[oneside, 11pt, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures={Required,Common,Contextual,TeX},Numbers=OldStyle, 
ItalicFont={HertzPro-BookItalic}, BoldFont={HertzPro-Bold}]{HertzPro-Book}

\newfontfamily{\petite}[Letters=PetiteCaps]{HertzPro-Book}

\begin{document}

This is \textsc{small caps} and this is {\petite petite caps}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Something like `\renewcommand\textsc[1]{\bgroup\petite#1\egroup}`?

Comment: Why don't you add `Letters=PetiteCaps` to the SmallCapsFeatures directly?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, how do I do that? please?

Comment: Check the documentation.

Comment: Have you tried providing the option `SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=PetiteCaps}` to the `\setmainfont` directive? (I can't try it out on my system since I don't have the "Hertz Pro" font family.)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you provide the option

```
SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=PetiteCaps}
```

to the `\setmainfont` directive:

```
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Required,Common,Contextual,TeX},
    Numbers=OldStyle, 
    ItalicFont={HertzPro-BookItalic}, 
    BoldFont={HertzPro-Bold},
    SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=PetiteCaps}
    ]{HertzPro-Book}
```

The `\newfontfamily{\petite}[Letters=PetiteCaps]{HertzPro-Book}` directive won't be needed anymore.